# How to access return value from deferred object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have the following code that uses `$.getJSON` inside the repository to return some data that is then used by other functions.

```
$.when(
    repository.getUserDetails().done(dataPrimer.getUserDetails),

    $.Deferred(
        function (deferred) {
           deferred.resolve();
        }
    )

).done(
   function () {
       repository.getUserPolicyTitles().done(dataPrimer.getUserPolicyTitles);
   },

   function () {
       repository.getUserPage().done();
   }
);
```

This works but I need to return a value from: `repository.getUserDetails().done(dataPrimer.getUserDetails)`
that can be used as a parameter to: `repository.getUserPage().done();`

The dataPrimer module for getUserDetails currently looks like this:

```
var getUserDetails = function (jsonString) {
    var object = parser.parse(jsonString);
    userDetails.userName = object.user.userName;
    userDetails.lastPolicyWorkedOn = object.user.lastPolicyWorkedOn;
    return userDetails.lastPolicyWorkedOn;
}
```

I have tried a few things such as `.pipe()` with no joy and want to be confident that I'm using a decent approach so I'm looking for the "best practice" way to return the parameter and use it in the `repository.getUserPage()` function please?

Comment: what's the point of the second auto-resolved object in the `$.when` block?

Comment: sorry, I don't know which object you mean - I'm just getting started with deferred and promises.  Basically, All I want to do is execute getUserDetails and do some processing, including returning some data and once that is done use this data as an input parameter to the other two functions (which don't have to be executed in order).  I would be really interested if there is a nicer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ["then"](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) . The "data" in example -- data returned by "getUserPolicyTitles" function.

```
$.when(
    repository.getUserDetails().done(dataPrimer.getUserDetails),

    $.Deferred(
        function (deferred) {
           deferred.resolve();
        }
    )

).done(function() {

    repository
        .getUserPolicyTitles()
        .done(dataPrimer.getUserPolicyTitles)
        .then(function(data) {
            repository.getUserPage().done();
        })

});
```

Comment: thanks, I had to rework as it was the return from getUserDetails I wanted but this did the trick.